# Android bottom navigation view has WHITE SPACE on the left and right

Tags: android, kotlin

Previously I had 3 items in my bottom navigation view, and 3 fragments associated with them. I am adding another item to it, and now there is white space on the sides, and I don't know where its coming from.

Here's the code for the bottom menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_learn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_learn"
        android:title="@string/title_learn" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_guided"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_lotus"
        android:title="@string/title_guided" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_profile"
        android:title="@string/title_profile" />

</menu>
```

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorBottomNavigationBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

[image]

Does anyone know what's causing the white space?

Comment: Can you tell if `Widget.BottomNavigationView` has any special margin attributes or something.. My guess it's a padding/margin right & left in the root layout.. can you share the entire layout?

Comment: Don't see nothing. It's all just 0dp. And fits well with 3 tabs, just with 4 tabs, we see this issue

Comment: just in case .. can you also set `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
```

to

```
 android:background="your color"
```

#1F1F1F

Comment: Really? It's an issue with the color? Rather than finding a way to expand the bottom navigation view to fit parent width

Comment: I made this inference from the source code. If it is wrong, can you try setting the padding values ​​to 0? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, android background and app item background

```
    android:background="@color/colorBottomNavigationBackground"
    
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorBottomNavigationBackground"
```